# Вопрос про JPA и Hibernate в частности

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java

Если на производстве уже существует база (огромная). И вот я не знаю. Я читал про спецификацию JPA и ORM штука удобная, но можно ли как то сделать так чтоб например Hibernate подхватил уже существующие таблицы или надо все таблице писать руками (то есть Java классы описывать а потом как то синхронизировать) , может я вообще не так все понимаю. Кто знает обьясните или подскажите как мне лучше сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Все уже давно придумано и написано. Есть такая тулза [Hibernate Tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html) (плагин для Eclipse), который позволяет в числе прочего генерировать настройки Hibernate для существующей схемы.

Answer (score 1):

Если пользуетесь коммерческой версией IntelliJ IDEA, то там есть встроенная генерация JPA-сущностей из таблиц БД. Чтобы не писать DAO руками можно воспользоваться [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) или [AutoDAO](http://autodao.sourceforge.net/)